# WPF C# Binding OnTargetPropetyChanged in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a DataGrid whose columns are defined in the code behind like this:

```
    MyGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
    {
        Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star),
        Header = "Name",
        Binding = new Binding("Name") { NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true},               
        ElementStyle = style,                
    });
```

My question is where do I call the `OnTargetUpdated` event in code behind?

Comment: Do you want to trigger the event or react to it from code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event should fire automatically since you set `NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true`. All you have to do is provide a method with a signature matching the event handler.

Have you tried simply putting the following method in your code behind?

```
private void OnTargetUpdated(Object sender, DataTransferEventArgs args)
{
    // Handle event
}
```

This is pretty much a straight copy from docs.microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-set-up-notification-of-binding-updates